# How to print hard link numbers with file names?

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to make a program

1. printing files that has the same inode numbers
2. printing the amount of hard links in the current directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
    DIR *dp;
    dp = opendir(".");

    struct dirent *dent1, *dent2;
   
    while((dent1 = readdir(dp))) {
        while((dent2 = readdir(dp))) {
            struct stat buf;
            if(stat(dent1->d_name, &buf)) {
                perror("stat");
                exit(1);
            }        
            if((dent1->d_ino == dent2->d_ino) && (dent1->d_name != dent2->d_name) {
                printf("---Same inode files---\n");
                printf("%s\n", dent1->d_name);
                printf("%s\n", dent2->d_name);
                printf("Number of hard links = %o\n", (unsigned int)buf.st_nlink);
                }
            }
        }
    closedir(dp);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code I wrote.

I used two loops to compare each files inode numbers.

There was no error in the program. But it didn't work well as I expected.

There were 3 hard links in the current directory, but it only printed one of them.

I know my coding skills are not good, but I did my best and this is as far as I can get on my own.

1. Is there anything wrong with my program?
2. Do I have to add something more?
3. Is my code inefficient?

Comment: You only do forward iteration of the `DIR` object `dp`, the inner loop will read all the remaining files from `dp`, and the outer loop will only iterate once. You need to [*seek*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seekdir.3.html) back to the beginning before the inner loop.

Comment: Also note that [`readdir`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) does not guarantee that it will return unique objects. There might be only one single object that it returns a pointer to, which means `dent1` will be the same as `dent2`.

Comment: Furthermore, you can't use `==` or `!=` to compare strings. To compare string you need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: All in all, it seems you have skipped not only reading the necessary documentation for the functions you use, you have also skipped some very important and basic part of C itself.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i guess you mean `strcmp` or `strncmp` instead of `strlen`

Comment: What do you mean by "amount of hard links in the current directory"?  Every name in a directory that refers to a regular file is a hard link.

Comment: Don't use 2 loops. Use one loop, and record the data.  eg, create a BST keyed on inode with an extra entry in each entry to record whether a duplicate has been seen.  When you are inserting into the tree, print names when you find a dup and set that flag.